# Adapter Pattern and packaging

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on a project that needs to be refactored in order to achieve decoupled modules.

I need to us an Adapter to decide which module to route to depending on some config.

```
                   +===========+
                   | Front-end |
                   +===========+
                    |         |
   +==================+      +==================+
   | RESTful Service1 |      | RESTful Service2 |
   +==================+      +==================+
                    |         |
             +=========================+      +=========+
             |          Adapter        | ---  | Config  |
             +=========================+      +=========+
               |          |          |
       +=========+   +=========+  +=========+
       | Module1 |   | Module2 |  | Module3 |
       +=========+   +=========+  +=========+
```

I have a Java application, and want to package the modules in JARS using Maven.

`RESTful Service1` will either talk to `Module1` or `Module2` while `RESTful Service2` will always talk to `Module3`. I need to establish which is the nest way to package these modules.

`RESTful Service1` will be in it's own Jar while `Module1` and `Module2` will have their own Jars too.

**Question**

Seeing that `RESTful Service2` will always talk to`Module3` only, should they be in the same Jar? Or should I separate them into two seperate Jars too?

Thanks

Comment: Would you want to update RS2 when Module1 changes?

Comment: @ScaryWombat the Modules just provide data in the response to the RESTful services. The RESTful services are stateless and just provide an interface for the front-end to get data from the modules.  In the future, the modules and RESTful services may change, but they will always be inline with each other, i.e. if Module 1 or 2 changes, then RESTful Service1 will change. If Module3 changes, then only RESTful Service2 will change.

Comment: Why is it that sometimes when I ask a question, people often do not answer the question but just give me more information that I may not want. (this time I left the question mark off the end)

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I have updated my answer above.  The answer is 'No'. RS2 and Module1 are not related. RS2 and Module3 are though.

Comment: So imagine that you have a customer who hates having his systems shutdown - If you have RS2 not having any common jars with RS1 (especially when the code it not even used), and RS1 needs shutting down, the your customer will be happier as he dowes not need to have RS2 shutdown as well.

Comment: It is not good practice to put your `Module 3` in with your REST web service.  Web services should just handle the data transferring from your database.  If you put `Module 3` into the RESTful web service then hopefully you need `Module 3` everywhere in future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RS2 when deployed always needs to work with M3, putting them in the same jar offers one benefit: we won’t forget M3 when deploying RS2. But the downside is that it is difficult to reuse and deploy M3 to another system which does not require RS2.

I think the benefit above is little. Often, when deploying a system you should have a document or checklist. Even if some component was forgotten, chance is that you could detect and fix it quickly.

So the better option is to seperate RS2 and M3 into two jars.